# Add jQuery UI Button to UI Dialog loaded from Ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm opening and closing dialogs that are dynamically created using ajax.  I'd like to be able to have the buttons that appear on the dialogs use the jQuery UI button.  I can do this by calling $("button").button(), but that affects every button element.  How can I be specific to only affect the buttons that appear on this dialog?

```
var $dialog = $('<div>').load('/Dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Dialog',
    height: 250,
    width: 750,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    show: "fadeIn",
    hide: "fadeOut"
});
$('#btnOpenDialog').click(function () {
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: please clarify, what exactly are you trying to do? You can just setup `buttons` within the `dialog()` method.

Comment: To clarify, I want to display a jQuery Dialog that is loaded from ajax.  It can have from 0 to 10 buttons on it.  I want to write a generic load function that will assign all of the buttons in the Dialog to use the jQuery UI Button without specifying each button ID and calling .button() on them individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use jAndy's suggestion and just use the Dialog buttons.  I was attempting to use already existing buttons in a HTML page I was loading through ajax.  The dialog buttons do what I need them to do and look cleaner.