# Ajax loaded Jquery button styles inside dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the exact problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181236/add-jquery-ui-button-to-ui-dialog-loaded-from-ajax/3181438#3181438), except that I do not want to use the Jquery UI dialog buttons. I want to use my own buttons from the form I loaded by ajax.

Is there a global override method for on all dialog loaded, I run a live event to attach the styles to the buttons or other content that was loaded by ajax inside the dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well when u load the dialog u can do this:
(if the class of ur buttons is `button-class`)

```
var $dialog = $('<div>').load('/Dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Dialog',
    height: 250,
    width: 750,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    show: "fadeIn",
    hide: "fadeOut"
});
//get the widget element
var $widg = $dialog.dialog('widget');
//find all buttons and apply button:
$("input:submit.jqBtn", $widg).button();
```

see fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/D8uYW/

Comment: I need to execute this code: $("input:submit.jqBtn").button(); to get the buttons to style

Comment: one sec ill change the last part

Answer (score 0):

In the dialog, you can call all the button elements and remove the class attribute on them, then apply the css you like.

```
$(":button").removeAttr("class").addClass("myClass");
```

where "myClass" is the style you want to apply to the buttons.

Comment: lol the OP is not using button elements... read the Q first ^_^